# Is there any better way to store unpacked values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a function which unpack 6 values and I'm storing those values in 6 variables but is there any better approach for unpacking those values and storing unlike writing large line of code.

```
var_value1,var_value2,var_value3,var_value4,var_value5,var_value6 = Some_function()
```

Note: I know that if I make variables names very small it will solve the problem but in real life scenario I need to provide variable names as they should understand by others as well. Thank You.

Comment: You can use exec() to create variables based on strings, the code isn't going to be prettier though:
Variables = some_function()
Variable_template = 'var_value'
for i,Variable in enumerate(Variables):
    exec(Variable_template+str(i)+'='+str(variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Indent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

or

- Create a dictionary, unpack there, 

  `var_val = Somefunction()._asdict()`


  and navigate using keys